# Grouping and/or Counting in R

Tags: r, count, grouping, tidyverse

I'm trying to 're-count' a column in R and having issues by cleaning up the data. I'm working on cleaning data by location and once I change CA to California.

```
 all_location <- read.csv("all_location.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 all_location <- count(all_location, location)
 all_location <- all_location[with(all_location, order(-n)), ]

  all_location

   A tibble: 100 x 2
    location        n
   <chr>       <int>
  1 CA           3216
  2 Alaska       2985
 3 Nevada        949
 4 Washington    253
 5 Hawaii        239
 6 Montana       218
 7 Puerto Rico   149
 8 California    126
 9 Utah           83
10 NA             72
```

From the above, there's CA and California. Below I'm able to clean grep and replace CA with California. However, my issue is that it's grouping by California but shows two separate instances of California.

```
  ca1 <- grep("CA",all_location$location)
  all_location$location <- replace(all_location$location,ca1,"California")

 all_location

A tibble: 100 x 2
 location        n
<chr>       <int>
 1 California   3216
 2 Alaska       2985
 3 Nevada        949
 4 Washington    253
 5 Hawaii        239
 6 Montana       218
 7 Puerto Rico   149
 8 California    126
 9 Utah           83
 10 NA             72
```

My goal would be to combine both to a total under n.

Comment: So replace CA with California _before_ you call `count()`....?

Comment: Also, check the cell padding (extra whitespace) on the existing version of "California" to make sure it's not really "California      ".  [trimws](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trimws.html) does a nice job of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_location$location[substr(all_location$location, 1, 5) %in% "Calif" ] <- "California"
```

to make sure everything that starts with "Calif" gets made into "California"

I am assuming that maybe you have a space in the California (e.g. `"California "`) that is already present which is why this is happening..

Comment: I ended up pulling the data back in and then grepped and replaced before I ran the count command.